# Rangy selection not working on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-edge, rangy

The below code snippet is working well for all browsers except Microsoft Edge.

```
$rootScope.highlights = $window.rangy.createHighlighter();
$rootScope.highlights.addClassApplier($window.rangy.createClassApplier('commented-text'));
$rootScope.highlights.highlightSelection('commented-text');
$window.getSelection().collapseToStart();
```

Is there anything we need to specifically add for Edge?

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Console tools to check whether there has some error? and use the Network tools to check whether the Rangy reference load success? Besides, from the document, it seems that it supports Microsoft Edge browser, please try to clear the browser cache and retest your code. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MSFT - Tried all of the above things, but no results yet.

Comment: No error and the reference load success? It seems that you are using angularjs,  can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to have two semicolons at the end of your first line?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, came to solution that **rangy.createHighlighter()** without any parameters won't work for Edge.

You need to specify the **"TextRange"** additional parameter (see below).

The default is "textContent".

```
$rootScope.highlights = rangy.createHighlighter(window.document, "TextRange");
```

Reference: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Highlighter-Module

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on the rangy github https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/368 with some kind of possible solution proposed.

> Commenting out the method on line 2277 of rangy-core.js

Maybe this can help you as well?

Comment: Thats a good solution, but editing the library is a bad practice :)